# DateTime parsing issue using @DateTimeFormat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, urlencode, java-time

I am getting issue while working with `@DateTimeFormat` in my `SpringBootApplication`. Below is the code snippet where I am getting the issue`

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@RestController
public class DateTimeController {

    @GetMapping("/test/datetime/{id}")
    public String testDateParsing(@PathVariable String id,
                                  @RequestParam("since") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz") LocalDateTime since) {

        System.out.println("id : " + id);
        System.out.println("since : " + since);

        return "success";
    }
}
```

The Code is working fine with datetime of EST time zone -

```
http://localhost:8080/test/datetime/1?since=2021-03-02T10:57:43-05:00 
- I am getting SUCCESS response for 2021-03-02T10:57:43-05:00 (EST Time)
```

The Code is `Not Working` with datetime of IST time zone -

```
http://localhost:8080/test/datetime/1?since=2021-03-02T10:57:43+05:30 
- I am getting ERROR response for 2021-03-02T10:57:43+05:30 (IST Time)
```

> **Exception -**
> "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to
> required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
> convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
> [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
> java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2021-03-02T10:57:43 05:30'; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed
> for value [2021-03-02T10:57:43 05:30]"

**Any idea how to fix this issue?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the + sign in your request URL. This is a reserved sign.

You must URL encode the query parameters. And this will then look like this:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/test/datetime/1?since=2021-03-02T10:57:43%2B05:30
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointing out the issue. I was thinking in a different direction altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The plus sign (`"+"`) in your URL is being automatically converted to a space character (`" "`).  This can be fixed by [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the space character as `"%2B"`.

```
http://localhost:8080/test/datetime/1?since=2021-03-02T10:57:43%2B05:30
```

This issue can be confirmed by a close read of the exception message, which is showing the parsed text as having a space in it, not the plus sign:

> ```
> Parse attempt failed for value [2021-03-02T10:57:43 05:30]"
> ```

This conversion of the plus sign to a space is a fairly common conversion in URLs, and it appears that Spring is doing this by default.